# code on a jpg image generated dynamically

Tags: php, image, jpeg

While I was looking for some info, I came across this image on a forum which i didn't understood how it worked. Its a JPG image which actually tells you your ip address and your browser. I think that maybe it was made by modifying htacess and replacing PHP for JPG, and with PHP generating the image dynamically but I'm not sure about it.

Would this be the way that this works?

Here is the image i saw:
http://www.danasoft.com/sig/475388.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing but etching text on image. There are several options to do it. Using PHP [see here](https://www.php.net/imagettftext) and Java [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929524/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-in-java)

Comment: but the file extension is .jpg , its because htaccess has been modify?

Comment: @gabrielmellace you can have file extension as .jpg or .png or anything else (what the library being used allows)

Answer (score 1):

yes this image is generating dynamically. It collects your info make a string and use some library to generate that image like in Captcha. php has its own library too for this purpose

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075553/gd-library-create-image-with-dynamic-text-on-it)