# Overlay text on image not renedered correctly when using custom hindi font with GD library functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, gd

I am trying to add overlay text to images using the GD library in php, while it works perfectly for characters in english, I am having rendering issues when the text is in hindi, even when the font used supports hindi text. Upon transformation and rendering on the image using the font, the result is not as desired.

I am using the font downloaded from here [RozhaOne](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rozha+One)

This is the code which I am executing

```
function createImageWithText()
{    
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->asset_url.'/images/input.jpeg');
    $fontSize = 32;
    list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf("#00bfff", "#%02x%02x%02x");
    $fontColor = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);
    $font = $this->asset_url.'/fonts/RozhaOne-Regular.ttf';
    $text = "कृति";
    
    imagettftext(
        $image,
        $fontSize,
        0,
        500,
        500,
        $fontColor,
        $font,
        $text
    );

    $save_path = $this->asset_url.'/images/output.png';
    imagepng($image, $save_path);
    imagedestroy($image);    
}
```

Actual Output
[image: Actual Output]

Expected Output
[image: Expected Output]

I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188046/writing-hindi-fonts-with-gd-library-do-not-render-as-desired) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075553/gd-library-create-image-with-dynamic-text-on-it) but it did not work when I am using the font specified or other hindi supported fonts.

This seems to be an issue with the GD library (Using php 7.4) handling hindi font, would be great to get some insights on how this can be solved/supported.